# How can I compare histograms between a digital image and it’s print

Tags: printing, color-management, image-processing, histogram, comparison

I want to compare color histograms between a digital photo and its physically printed in cloth (like a T-shirt) version. The process is simple:

1. Printing a digital image (with good resolution) in a T-shirt
2. Take a picture of that printed T-shirt in proper alignment and crop
3. Compare histograms

As one might expect, the color histogram of the photo of the printed T-shirt is very different from the original image, as it should be. What I want to know is if there is any known method to achieve one of the following:

1. From original digital image, transform colors so to be closer to printed colorspace histogram.
2. From printed T-shirt photo, try to normalize or transform in some way to achieve back original colors.

I am aware that the color distribution of the printed T-shirt depend also on the camera that captures it. Right now I am thinking of training a ML model to try to learn the color transformation between two colors distributions (original and physically printed).

However, I wonder if there is some literature about that or some procedure I can perform using my camera to try to find that color transformation so I can apply to other prints.

My goal is to generalize (predict) the printed color distribution transformation from original digital image. As I'm always using the same printer for print, and the same camera for the photo of the T-shirt, I guess this should be feasible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While the idea you have, is the right one, there is already an established way to do that: you will find more about that under color-management in print.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point some more keywords of techniques related? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered just printing one or more test patterns and measuring the transformation directly?

Comment: @Caleb you mean like a linear transformation using a set of print vs imaged color correspondences? That looks interesting. But what if the transform is somehow non linear and complex? Which model do I use for this transformation? Some colors in original data are perfect colors like (1,0,0) and they become a smooth distribution of red after print and captured by photo. Also the mean of distribution gets shifted. I have no idea of which model to use for this transformation.

Comment: @Caleb my idea of a ML mode was exactly to address this lack of knowledge of transformation model. The color correspondences can be used to train that unknown mode by creating a ML mode with lots of parameters.

Comment: This looks like a standard color calibration process. Been done for decades without using ML. To get enough data for ML would cost you a lot in T-Shirts...

Comment: True, although I can have access to the current production line and use current products to build the dataset. But I think you are right, it looks like a color calibration procedure. I will take a look on that for now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Based on your comment on Bob's answer, is your goal to be able to color correct the output or to be able to identify the original image based on the t-shirt (or vice versa)? (For example to print the shipping label and packing slip or to use the image of the t-shirt in the shipping confirmation email)

Comment: @LightBender yes, kind of. The actual goal is to solve ties for a CBIR (content based image retrieval) system. I already search for images using specific feature descriptors that are rotation, scale and translation invariant. It works very well, but those descriptions are also color invariant at some level. So sometimes if two products have same structure but different color details, I will find both as being the same product in terms of feature matching. So for this case I need to untie using some other metric. Color histograms in this case can help, but only if the system is color calibrated

Comment: If you know what types of images you're putting into the system when you add them, why not just include that in the metadata. "Find everything that matches X and filter by metadata A, B, C and Q." I don't know if it's a common example, but one of the books I read on machine learning, when talking about poor uses, used the example of building a network to identify the species of animal in a vet's database by picture when the species is one of the standard questions asked when making an appointment.

Comment: @LightBender I see your point and your example make sense. But in my case, database pictures are: 1) any kind of picture, even some abstract thing or drawing; 2) Images are created and added directly by user, so I have no control over them. User can choose to print just any tshirt using custom images that are often abstract illustrations, so I have no proper method of tagging. My “tags” are feature descriptors which are some very well defined features in image’s gradient space. Those represent the image fairly well.

Comment: Hi Pablo. Based on your question and these comments, it doesn't sound like this question is really about photography. It sounds like this is more in the realm of either ML & statistics (i.e., suited for [stats.se]) or perhaps more generalized image processing (i.e., better at [dsp.se]). Do either of those sites seem like a good fit?

Comment: @scottbb hi scott, its funny that you mentioned it, because I first posted it in stats forum, but people recommended me to post here, lol. Nobody answered there. Maybe my question was not so well written anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @PabloCarneiroElias Ah. I'm sorry you didn't get any traction over at Stats-SE. I don't think it's a matter of not being well-written; it seems written fairly well for the right context. I'm just struggling with the topicality in a photographic context. However, there's been very little objection (via vote-to-close because of being off-topic), so I'm in no rush to close it or move it. You've gotten an answer and perhaps some help, so that's good. =)

Comment: @scottbb yes, thanks! I have some ideas. I realized what I might need is just old plain color calibration. Im yet to perform the test due to client taking time to print my custom colorchecker. As soon he does, I will test and check if results are satisfying or I might need some other clue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The industry standard method would use two transforms encoded as [ICC profiles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile). The input device would use an mapping from its color characteristics to the Profile Connection Space. Likewise the output would use a mapping from the Profile Connection Space to its output color space.

This is the standard because it allowed for connecting any input device to any output device.

Going backwards from the print isn’t really possible in a direct way. You need an input device (such as a camera or scanner) to capture an image of the print. And then you are dependent on its ICC profile (or a logical equivalent) to get back into Profile Connection Space.

That is not to say you can’t do it…that’s what printer profiling hardware does.

Anyway, the way to do the sort of things you want to do is available off the shelf from companies such as Xrite and DataColor using ICC profiles. It is not cheap. But it is as cheap as it gets.

Comment: Thanks. In my case Im developing a CBIR (content based image retrieval) and I need to develop the color calibration myself as part of the product.

Comment: @PabloCarneiroElias (a->b & b->c) -> a->c. That’s why you can use ICC profiles for any arbitrary transformation. But the transformations are determined empiricaly by measure. You can’t reason precisely about how multiple inks combine on a particular physical medium. Math won’t get the right answer. Empirical results are required.

Comment: Yes, there is no way of easily understanding chemically how the medium affects light absortion/reflection. Also, the camera colorspace can indeed be modeled separated. However, since I am always using the same printer and same camera, what matters for me is the overall final result of print + camera capture. So a final colorchecker that was printed then captured and compared with original rgb values is enough to create the model for correction, like an unified model.